# information that there is

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

Is it possible for noun "information" to take on content clause as below?

"I have some information that there is a guy with a gun in the building."

"I have some information that a girl was cheating on you with the another boy."

Thank you!

Comment: Anecdotally, i.e. speaking as a native speaker, not as a linguist: yes, that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, but that usage of "information" is *pretentious*, it makes the speaker sound like a weaselly government official, perhaps one with access to cohorts willing to act like spies.

> "I have some information that there is a guy with a gun in the building."

This might mean either:

1. that a source which the speaker believes to be reliable has *informed* said
   speaker that someone has a gun.
2. that the speaker doesn't necessarily trust their own source, but   *wishes* us to suppose that source *is* reliable.  This way, if there is no gunman, and it's only a rumor, the speaker needn't *lose face* -- the speaker was not lying, or even incorrect, but rather his source of *information* was to blame.

> "I have some information that a girl was cheating on you with the *[sic]* another boy."

Same double implication as the other quote.  Might be true, or *not true*, the payload is the ability to borrow the ears of listeners with sensational but insubstantial allegations.  It's like *The National Enquirer* school of journalism: that paper doesn't much care whether an informer is correct so long as there's a lively headline in it.

Answer (score 0):

In an informal conversation, no one would think twice if you used that structure.

In a formal setting, on the other hand, I would recommend throwing in a more active word. For example, the Merriam-Webster dictionary follows *information* with *about* or *on* in all of their example sentences.

You might could try switching "information" to some conjugation of *to inform*. For example,

> "My superior just informed me via radio that we must evacuate immediately: a gunman prowls the building has we speak!"

While this style and format may be a little "extra," it really does make your writing more engaging, more formal, and perhaps more technically correct!

In addition (while it's not the most savvy), you could turn "information" into the subject and try something along the lines of, "I have information stating that ..."

Comment: Nobody should stop and rephrase a warning in "more formal language" when there's a guy with a gun in the building. There's a time for formality, and that's just not it.